# How can I export a Numbers 3.x chart to PDF?

Tags: pdf, numbers

I created a chart in Numbers 3 (version 3.6.2). In earlier versions of Numbers I could copy the chart and paste it into, e.g., Adobe Illustrator as a PDF vectorgraphic.

In 3.6.2, copy and paste results in a blurry (low resolution) bit mapped image being pasted.

How can I get a PDF version of my chart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. open the context menu on the chart (e.g., control-click or right-mouse click)
2. select *Copy as PDF*.
3. paste into application (e.g. Adobe Illustrator) or in Preview create a new file with *File* -> *New from Clipboard* and save as PDF.

When copied and pasted in this way, the chart remains a high-resolution vector graphic.